# How to assign an image to Image Node by its name

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

For example I load 2 images (with suffixes: _normal and _color) into Blender. 
I'm using this code for importing images:

```
supported_file_types = '.png', '.jpg', '.tif', '.hdr', '.bmp', '.dds', '.psd'
def path_iterator(path_name):
for fp in os.listdir(path_name):
    if fp.endswith(supported_file_types) and ((bpy.context.scene.color_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.normal_map_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.height_map_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.metallic_map_string) in fp[-12:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.rough_string) in fp[-15:]):
        yield fp
```

Then I have those images in Image Editor.

[image]

How to find imported image by its suffix and assign to Image Node? I can't use the exact name of those textures just suffix, so this method won't work:

```
image_node.image = bpy.data.images['YOUR_IMAGE_NAME']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can iterate over the currently referenced images in `bpy.data.images`.

```
def get_img_reference(suffix):
    images = bpy.data.images
    for img in images:
        if suffix in img.name:
            return img

img = get_img_reference('_Roughness')
if img:
   image_node.image = img
```

It's possible to write this shorter but the extra checking is a sanity check. This is case sensitive, beware :)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know the exact name of the textures. I know only the suffix "_roughness".

Comment: you may want to learn more about Python string object, it's not strictly a Blender issue. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. I will check this link.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to search only in just imported images? When I use this addon three times I will have three different images but with the same suffix.

Comment: not really, you might be able to use the `bpy.data.images[0].filepath` to your advantage, or make a `set()` from the names of images present before importing, then do a boolean `difference` on the `set()` of image names after importing, and only use the new ones. But this is a separate question which I'm happy to answer _If_ you ask as a new Question (not adding it to this question)