# How to add images by suffixes to Image Nodes only from the latest import

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have the code which import new images by names.

```
supported_file_types = '.png', '.jpg', '.tif', '.hdr', '.bmp', '.dds', '.psd'
def path_iterator(path_name):
    for fp in os.listdir(path_name):
        if fp.endswith(supported_file_types) and ((bpy.context.scene.color_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.normal_map_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.height_map_string) in fp[-10:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.metallic_map_string) in fp[-12:]) or ((bpy.context.scene.rough_string) in fp[-15:]):
            yield fp
```

and

```
def get_img_reference(suffix):
    images = bpy.data.images
    for img in images:
        if suffix in img.name: 
            return img
```

I have also a text input (I write here suffix by which new images are imported)

```
box.prop(context.scene, "color_string")
```

I'm adding images to nodes by this command:

```
img_node_color.image = get_img_reference((bpy.context.scene.color_string))
```

If I use this addon, for example three times for different textures I will get textures named accordingly: tex_color, tex2_color, tex3_color. 
Now adding textures to Image Nodes by suffix "color" won't work.

This Question is related with [how-to-assign-an-image-to-image-node-by-its-name](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/how-to-assign-an-image-to-image-node-by-its-name/40143?noredirect=1#comment66620_40143)

How to select images by suffix from latest import and add them to Image Nodes?

Comment: Can you List your image files with the precise filenames and extensions?

Comment: Those files have image's extensions. Filenames are changeable and the suffix is the only one constant element.

Comment: please define the problem better.